# Как подружить файл с программой и файл с GUI на Java?

Tags: java, gui, if, jframe

Вопрос в следующем, уважаемые знатоки: есть файл с алгоритмом, состоящим из if/else, который естественно требует от пользователя ввода через (java.util.Scanner) параметра if в виде boolean true или false в консоли. И есть второй файл с GUI,в котором в Jframe создано окно, в котором есть две кнопки (одна true, вторая false). Собственно вопрос: как переделать файл с кодом так, чтобы переменная, которой сейчас присваивается значение из консоли, присваивала бы его из файла с GUI по нажатию Jbutton1 или JButton? Нутром чую, что нужно что-то мутить со слушателем кнопки и геттерами и сеттерами, но в силу еще небольших познаний в Java разобраться не могу. Буду всем очень благодарен за советы, т.к. изучаю Java сам и спросить больше не у кого.

```
package copy.AlgoritmOtboraMonetPoITK1;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Man {


    
    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });


        boolean answer1;
        System.out.println("Гроздь №2 имеет форму прямоугольного треугольника? ");
        answer1 = in.nextBoolean();

       

        if (answer1 == true) {
            System.out.println("Это разновидность АА");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Гроздь №2 имеет форму тупоугольного треугольника, " + "\n" +
                    "в грозди №5 черенок подходит к первой ягоде слева?");
            answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
            if (answer1 == true) {
                System.out.println("Размер изображения меньше (венок отдален от канта)?");
                answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
                if (answer1 == true) {
                    System.out.println("Это разновидность ЕА");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Это разновидность ЕБ");
                }


            } else {
                System.out.println("В грозди №5 крайняя правая ягода посредине буквы П?");
                answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
                if (answer1 == true) {
                    System.out.println("В 4 и 8 гроздьях есть черенки?");
                    answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
                    if (answer1 == true) {
                        System.out.println("Это разновидность ВА");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Это разновидность ГА");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("У монеты есть кант?");
                    answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
                    if (answer1 == true) {
                        System.out.println("Ягоды большие и слипаются?");
                        answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
                        if (answer1 == true) {
                            System.out.println("Это разновидность ДА");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(" В гроздьях 7 и 8 черенки подходят к ягодам?");
                            answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
                            if (answer1 == true) {
                                System.out.println("Это разновидность БА");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Правый отросток листа между гроздьями №1 и №2" + "" +
                                        "\n" + "широкий?");
                                answer1 = in.nextBoolean();
                                if (answer1 == true) {
                                    System.out.println("Это разновидность ББ");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Это разновидность БВ");
                                }


                            }

                        }


                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Это разновидность ДВ");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
package copy.AlgoritmOtboraMonetPoITK1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.Console;

public class Main implements ActionListener {

    public Main() {

        initComponents();
    }

    private JFrame viewForm;

    private void initComponents() {
        viewForm = new JFrame("Помощник");
        viewForm.setSize(600, 600);
        viewForm.setVisible(true);
        viewForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel L_pic= new JLabel();
        L_pic.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\123.jpg"));
        L_pic.setVisible(true);
        L_pic.setLocation(172,150);
        L_pic.setSize(200,200);
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(L_pic);
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(new JLabel());

        JLabel field = new JLabel("Отбор монет 25 копеек по разновидностям");
        field.setVisible(true);
        field.setLocation(150, 10);
        field.setSize(300,20);
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(field);
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(new JLabel());



        JButton button = new JButton("Yes");
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.setLocation(150, 500);
        button.setSize(100, 30);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //Что здесь написать никак не пойму...


                System.out.println(false);

            }


        });
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(button);
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(new JLabel());




        JButton button1 = new JButton("No");
        button1.setVisible(true);
        button1.setLocation(300, 500);
        button1.setSize(100, 30);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//Что здесь написать никак не пойму...

                }

        });
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(button1);
        viewForm.getContentPane().add(new JLabel());





            };
















    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: добавляйте код, потому как по другому что-то советовать можно только в духе "вешайте слушатель на кнопку", что будет явно недостаточно

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Код разместил.

Comment: боюсь, что в вашем случае никак. код в классе Man представляет собой набор вложенных условных операторов. ничего хуже быть не может в принципе. в джаве невозможно запустить метод другого класса не сначала (goto к счастью не имплементировано), а значит вы не сможете пошагово продвигаться по вашему методу, подставляя вместо консольных команд результаты пользовательского ввода. даже если вы подставите в Scanner какой-то InputStream , и будете передавать данные через него, у вас не будет обратной связи с вьюхой и все текстовые уведомления попадут в консоль.

Comment: Большое спасибо за комментарий! Буду думать над изменением кода в классе Man. А если if -ы заменить на switch или вместо каждого if сделать отдельный метод? Какая-то реализация на Java должна же быть?

Comment: разумеется потенциально возможных реализаций много. но однозначно логику нужно вытягивать из одного метода. я бы в этом случае смотрел в сторону паттерна цепочка обязанностей. для начала метод main переместите в класс вьюхи. почему у вас вьюху запускает сторонний класс? это нарушение паттерна GRASP Creator. А еще в классах с логикой для начала не должно быть статики.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду работать.

Comment: У вас только одна панель, на которой вы разместили кнопки. Если вы хотите реализовать логику ввода с консоли, но кнопки надо добавлять после ввода очередного значения, что приводит к динамическому программированию, то есть не есть хорошо для новичка. Поэтому надо подготовить несколько диалогов для ввода значений их чекбоксов или радио кнопки. По нажатию кнопки диалог закрывается и вы берете из него значения полей. Сверяете ответ, и открываете соответствующий диалог. Как-то так.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказки и объяснение моих просчетов! Искренне благодарю за потраченное на меня время!